# Android app page showing nothing

Tags: android, facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Blank page on facebook android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11912609/blank-page-on-facebook-android-app)

I have made an android app and registered on facebook.

https://apps.facebook.com/norway_eid_greetings/

the app page shows nothing unlike other app pages ..

help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to embed a page that prevents embedding due to X-Frame-Options. (Check your JavaScript console). Embeddding one facebook page within another isn't permitted.

```
Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options.
```

Comment: how should I avoid this ? Kindly help