# Blank page on facebook android app

Tags: android, facebook

https://apps.facebook.com/norway_eid_greetings/

I have made this android app and registered on facebook.

I have given

canvas url to be http://apps.facebook.com/norway_eid_greetings/

secured canvas url to be https://apps.facebook.com/norway_eid_greetings/

mobile web url to be http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=352658298145952

now the app says that it is experiencing a problem

please help !

Comment: possible reasons may be: no canvas url setting, you have not set base domain for your app. or you are running it in sandbox mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set:

```
canvas url: http://apps.facebook.com/norway_eid_greetings/

secured canvas url: https://apps.facebook.com/norway_eid_greetings/

mobile web url: http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=352658298145952
```

Because you can't edit those page.

You must have a website and set:

```
canvas url: http://myweb.com/norway_eid_greetings/

secured canvas url: https://myweb.com/norway_eid_greetings/

mobile web url: http://www.myweb.com/norway_eid_greetings/mobile/
```

Now you have to develop in your website those pages and when you connect to http://apps.facebook.com/norway_eid_greetings/ you'll see what you have developped like a window on your website

Comment: can you please tell how I m going to do this website thing ?

Comment: you should create a website (if you don't have one), write a little bit of code in simple language (HTML, CSS, PHP) try with <h1>Hi I am khuram</h1>, and connect this page to facebook canvas, so when you'll see your app page in facebook you'll see a big text "I am khuram" displayed

Answer (score 0):

You must use as canvas url, secure....... th url where you hosted the app like http://www.domain.com/myapp not the canvas page

Answer (score 0):

you should follow these tutorials
 [fb-developer](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/) and 
[fb-implemetation](http://ericosgood.com/prog/facebook-android-sdk-tutorial/).